Personal(ized) dictionary application
What Android app would allow you to edit a dictionary for a constructed language (using all standard dictionary features, including, defining terms, adding pictures, storing etimology, and download and search and combine existing terms and store them as entries from multilingual sources, and criteria for sorting terms written with all charcters from a Unicode character set, thus program stuff to do with collation (like ch in Spanish).
Advantages could be storing pictures of food items or adding terms containing experiences with personal names.
For example, imagine a dictionary with terms like this:
Bubibo - experience experienced when David throws the ball
Where can I find such a dictionary application?
Thanks.

Have you tried investigating any of the "hits" from a pretty basic Google search? If so, what did you find deficient about the ones you've tried?

what dictionary application allows adding pictures? this does not seem standard to me at all

It sounds like rather than a dictionary you are looking for is effectively a Wiki that given the selection then comes down to only on the one device or hosted and so accessible from multiple devices & possibly by multiple users.
Hosting your own on Android is likely to be complex and, if you loose your phone, vulnerable.
For some details on possible hosting sites you can look here.
